# Asynchronous function not updating variable

Tags: ios, swift

```
        var endLat: Double = 0.0
        var endLong: Double = 0.0

              func forwardGeocodingStarting(address: String) {
            CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                let placemark = placemarks?[0]
                let location = placemark?.location
                let coordinate = location?.coordinate

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    startLat = (coordinate?.latitude)!
                    startLong = (coordinate?.longitude)!
                    print("\(startLat) is lat and \(startLong) is long")
                }
            })
        }
```

Hello, here is a geocoding function that I created, that simply takes an address and returns the address's coordinates. My problem is, that at the end of the code section, when I do `print(endLat)` it prints out 0, however when I do it in the `dispatch_async` in the function, it comes out to the proper latitude.

I realize this is an asynchronous function, which is why I tried to use the `dispatch_async` to update the variable instantly.

My question is, how can I have these variables update instantly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a little confused with what you mean by `"Asynchronous function not updating variable"`. `forwardGeocodingStarting(_:)` is **NOT** an Async function. `geocodeAddressString` is an async function designed by the API to allow you to use the following `values` you get after the operation is done within that function only. Hence you keep getting 0 as the it doesn't wait till the operation is done completely to display the value. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue)` is used only to update UI on the Main thread. You've to use a completion handler in your function like so:

```
 typealias theDouble = (Double, Double) -> ()  

 func forwardGeocodingStarting(address: String, completion: theDouble){
//your code
let aVar: Double!
let bVar: Double!

let placemark = placemarks?[0]
let location = placemark?.location
let coordinate = location?.coordinate
aVar = (coordinate?.latitude)!
bVar = (coordinate?.longitude)!
completion(aVar, bVar)
}
```

Now when you call your function, update the variables `startLat` and `startLong` like so:

```
forwardGeocodingStarting(<your string address>) { firstVar, secondVar in

startLat = firstVar
startLong = secondVar
 print("\(startLat) is lat and \(startLong) is long") //You will get correct values

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work, however, when I try to use `startLat` and `startLong` after calling the function, it still returns 0

Comment: I tried to edit your post so you could see what I meant.

Comment: I got it. So you're saying it prints fine in the line `print("\(startLat) is lat and \(startLong) is long")` ? But when you call `startLat` and `startLong` outside the function call, it says 0?

Comment: Exactly. I need to use these values throughout the code, so I need it to work outside the call function. Thanks for responding

Comment: Declare those two variables at the top of the class! Have you? Like global variables. Then you can use them. Did you try that?

Comment: I have, but when I call them outside of the call function, like where i put the edit on your code, it returns 0.

Comment: I think you've initialised the two vars as 0. Just do a :Int! And try?

Comment: You are correct, I did initialize them as 0. However, when I did them as Double!'s, it returned nil.

Comment: @willcohen Were you able to fix it? I am having the same problem as you. The variables are not updating outside the call function for me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have these variables update instantaneously, as you are calling an *asynchronous* function. Thats an obvious contradiction :-)

That you dispatch back to the main queue is fine, but that doesn't change the asynchronous behaviour. In fact your are even issuing yet another `dispatch_async` ... (meaning the body of that code will get run at some later point in time)

You could wait for the results to be available, e.g. using a [dispatch group](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/), but quite likely that is not what you want here.
I assume you want to use the values in some view controller? In this case you probably fill in some instance variables as the results arrive and update the UI state once both values are available.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would I wait until the results arrive? Like, is there a build in swift method to run after they arrive? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, yes, the block you pass to the `completionHandler` in your code is the block which is run when the results are ready to be processed. You already figured that one out: "when I do it in the dispatch_async in the function, it comes out to the proper latitude"

Comment: I have edited my original post to where I thought I should alter my code to put it there. The only problem is, when I did that, it no longer recognized coordinate.latitude & coordinate.longitude

Comment: Because you declare `coordinate` within the `if placemarks?.count > 0` block? Please take time to review and debug your code before you respond.

Comment: I edited my entire code to address your suggestions, but it still is printing out 0. Any idea why this could be happening? Thanks again for helping.